# SoapUI datasource always reference last value

Tags: groovy, soapui

In soapUI, I am referecing a data source value through this code in groovy script.

```
 "${context.expand( '${DataSource#dpid}')}"
```

I can see the replaced value in result but it only gives me the last value. I've tried using file and grid data source. same results for both. How can I configure data source so it starts from the first value and iterate until last row. (I've added a data loop step and given the target as groovy script).  Thanks!

Comment: What version of SoapUI? What options do you have turned on for the DataSource step?

Comment: @SiKing , SoaUI pro 5.0.0. On "Set option for datasource" panel , I've "restarts on run" and "expand" checked.

Comment: I use various DataSources all the time, never with a problem. Something else must be going on. Post steps to reproduce! See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @SiKing , I am thinking what else I can provide. If I do a simple `log.info(context.expand( '${DataSource#dpid}'))` in groovy script it prints out the last value. When I run data source I, I can see all rows have been fetched from text file and I can see them in "data log" window with msg "Got7 rows in 0ms" , that means data is available to be used. am i using it correct way? Is anything else needs to be added to context.expand statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood how SoapUI, and especially the DataSource step, works.

When you are creating/debugging your test, you will normally press play on the DataSource step, and enter a value in the popup. This will retrieve the specified number of steps and show them to you in the data log. When you "play" one of the subsequent steps in your test, that references your DataSource value, only the last one retrieved will be expanded.

When you run the entire test, assuming you set everything up correctly, the test will iterate over all the values, one at a time. When you run the test you can see the soapui log print out messages like "current row = X". You can also look through the history of the test steps, or you can insert a step that simply prints out the value to the log `log.info(context.expand( '${DataSource#dpid}'))`, and you should see all the values.